# Overlapping audio file to one

Tags: android, audio

I need of create an audio file with two audio files as input. That is, One audio file having speech and another having background music, i want to mix those files and output the third(mixed)file. I googled for last two days but nothing find useful. Please provide me some suggestions. Thanks.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What format are the files?  MP3 or .WAV?  Something else?  If .wav, what format are the audio samples (16-bit int, float, etc.?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use FFMPEG util compiled for Android to merge two audio files to one file, but it's pretty hard to compile it and also you will need to write wrapper class to run it on Android like from command line.

Comment: I don't think so. FFMPEG is most popular solution for working with audio and video on android, IMHO.